# Calling the Operating System from CLIPS

Tags: system-calls, clips

I am trying to call system function from CLIPS environment. I've used the example given in the Programming Tutorial however it doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu. I used the following code but I got the message:

> System function not fully defined for this system.

My code:

```
(defrule start-program ""
    (not (started on))
    =>
    (assert (print-directory /home/username/Desktop))
    (assert (started on))
)

(defrule print-directory
    (print-directory ?directory)
    =>
    (system "ls " ?directory)
)
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've checked the file sysdep.c and found that my machine Ubuntu 12.04 is not considered valid operating system in order to execute system command. Here is the code:
#if VAX_VMS
  .....
#endif

#if   UNIX_7 || UNIX_V || IBM_MSC || IBM_TBC || IBM_ICB || IBM_ZTC || IBM_SC || IBM_MCW || IBM_GCC || MAC_XCD
  ......
#else

#if ! VAX_VMS
   EnvPrintRouter(theEnv,WDIALOG,
            "System function not fully defined for this system.\n");
#endif

#endif

Comment: I've change the lines 800-815 in sysdep.c in order to run the code on Ubuntu machine and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running version 6.24, try changing the flag in setup.h from GENERIC to either UNIX_V or UNIX_7 and recompile. If you're running version 6.3, try changing the flag in setup.h from GENERIC to LINUX and if that doesn't work try UNIX_V or UNIX_7.